# Separating lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, parsing, notepad++

I was wondering if it was possible to use a regex command to find just "Username" only
The current document I have looks something like this

```
Username: Biu2l40  
Occupation: IT  
Age: 24  

Username: John1  
Occupation: IT  
Age: 29  

Username: Redsock234  
Occupation: Janitor  
Age: 22
```

I'd like to find a way to make it so its

```
Username: Biu2l40  
Username: John1  
Username: Redsock234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to do so with these expressions,

```
 (Username:.*\s)|.*\n
 (Username:.*\s)|.*\r?\n
```

based on [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s advice, which are much simpler and faster:

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/uzposI/2)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/v7jPZD/1)

than this expression:

```
 (Username:.*\s)|[\s\S]*?
```

which might also work, and the replace can be `$1`.

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/uzposI/1/)

#### Advice

[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) advice is that:

> but [I] would change the right side [of the third expression] to something like `|.*\n` or `|.*\r?\n`
> for better performance. don't see the reason for `|[\s\S]*?` even
> `|[\s\S]` has fewer steps.

Comment: good idea! but would change the [right side to something like `|.*\n` or `|.*\r?\n`](https://regex101.com/r/uzposI/2) for better performance. don't see the reason for `|[\s\S]*?` even `|[\s\S]` has fewer steps =)

Answer (score 0):

The following will match "Username: " and everything after it except line breaks. This includes spaces.

```
/Username: .*/g
```

**[Demo](https://regexr.com/4fsod)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead `^(?!Username:` to assert that the string does not start with Username: and then match any character except a newline `.*` followed by matching 0+ times a unicode newline sequence `\R*`

In the replacement using an empty string.

**Find what**

```
^(?!Username:).*\R*
```

**Replace with**

Leave empty

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fz7NKK/1)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- Find what: `^Username:\h*.+`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- *Check Bookmark line*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  Username:     # literally
  \h*           # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
```

[image]

**After all lines were marked:**

- Search menu > Bookmark
- Remove Unmarked Lines

[image]

Comment: @codylei: I'm surprise you unmarked this answer. Have you tried the other answer in Notepad++? It doesn't work!